# Map Informations with fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have a map with some pinpoints that, if you click on them show some information. The plan was, that I can click a Icon and it shows a div, if I now click the same icon the div will disapear.

As long as i got show() it works but if I put in fadeIn() it reapears on the second click.

Here my script so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(".icon-location").on('click', function(event){
          $('[id^="ort-box-"]').fadeOut('slow');
        });


        var mouseX;
        var mouseY;
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
           mouseX = e.pageX;
           mouseY = e.pageY;
        });

        $(".icon-location").on('click', function(event){
            var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#ort-box-"+currentId).show().css({position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX, "z-index":"998"});
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Max I got something startet but there is some logic mistake I must have made.

```
$(".icon-location").on('click', function(event){
            $('[id^="ort-box-"]').fadeOut('slow');

        if(!$(this).hasClass('ortActive')){

                    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
                    $("#ort-box-"+currentId).fadeIn('slow').css({position:"absolute", top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX, "z-index":"998"});        

            $(this).addClass('ortActive');
        }else {
            $(this).removeClass('ortActive');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why `ready()` inside `ready()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching 2 eventhandlers on the same DOM element.
So if you click on it, both handlers will fire the event and both functions will be called.

Maybe use something like

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

if you trigger the event for the first time, check when you press again with

```
if($(this).hasClass('active')){ ... 

  $(this).removeClass('active');
}
```

This way you can be sure, that you can trigger only the wanted parts of the event handlers.

Comment: It is a really good idea but it still doesnt work. I edited my post with the new thing

Comment: you're now binding the event on the ortActive trigger.
But you need to use the  if(element.hasClass(...))
inside the function of the click event
 $(".icon-location").on('click', function(event){
       if($(this).hasClass('ortActive'){
             $('[id^="ort-box-"]').fadeOut('slow');       
       }
  });

Comment: I need to delete all the divs everytime i click one of the Icons (icon-location) so does it have to be like my new edit? The if is now after the onclick and there is only one onclick.

Comment: Okay it worked at the end, just had to make some small chances